# Storage Limits for PWAs in iOS Safari (2021)?

Tags: web, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

What are the actual storage limits in iOS safari for a PWA (in either localstorage or indexeddb)?

Is there anyway to request more storage?

Is iOS guaranteed to keep the data? (i.e. not automatically delete it)

Comment: Have you got any updates on this, i am facing an issue that ios safari is clearing my users website data, for whole 1 year i am trying to find an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155850/invalidstateerror-failed-to-execute-transaction-on-idbdatabase-the-databas

Comment: No response.  From personal experience we have found that storing the data in indexeddb (IDB) on a pinned PWA seems to be more persistent.  Apparently it also depends on available space on the device as well however I haven't found a concrete list of rules that iOS safari uses to clear the data. We found IDB on iOS to be unstable and it would silently (without error) crash around 3 times a day and could only be fixed by a refresh (This is for a single-page-app that stays open and is used constantly for the entire day). Fix was saving state and triggering a page refresh when idle every hour